# Process a list while appending it in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there some kind of list like collection I can use in .NET to allow me to append to it while iterating?

```
var ls = new List<int>();
ls.Add(5);

foreach (var v in ls) {
    if (v > 0)
        ls.Add(v - 1);
}

//Alternative
var e = ls.GetEnumerator();
while (e.MoveNext()) {
    if (e.Current > 0)
        ls.Add(e.Current - 1);
}
```

Comment: Can't you just keep things simpler and append to a different container?

Comment: You can't use an enumerator and modify the collection while enumerating.  So just don't, List doesn't *require* you to use an enumerator to find its elements back.  Use a for(;;) loop instead, easy peasy.  Or generally add to another collection and merge afterwards.

Answer (score 6):

To mimic such `foreach` loop, I suggest using `for` loop, while iterating *backward*:

```
for (int i = ls.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
  var v = ls[i];

  //TODO: put relevant code from existing foreach loop here  
}
```

Or if you have to loop *forward*

```
int n = ls.Count; // we don't want iterate the items appended

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
  var v = ls[i];

  //TODO: put relevant code from existing foreach loop here  
}
```

In case you do want itetate appended items (see comments below) standard `for` loop is enough:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ls.count; ++i) {
  var v = ls[i];

  //TODO: put relevant code from existing foreach loop here  
}
```

Finally, you can iterate a *copy* of the original list:

```
foreach (var v in ls.ToList()) { // ls.ToList() is a shallow copy of the ls
  ...
}
```

Comment: I do want to iterate appended items. That's actually the point. <strike>However you can't do ls[i]. You can do ElementAt but that has performance issues.</strike> since when can we use list like arrays!?!?!

Comment: @acidzombie24 all the time. It was always a ~dynamic~ array (i.e. .net version of std::vector).

Answer (score 2):

Using `for` would allow this. `foreach` does not allow for the modification of a enumerable while iterating it.

```
var ls = new List<int>();
ls.Add(5);

for (int i = 0; i < ls.Count; i++) {
  var v = ls[i];
  if (v > 0)
      ls.Add(v - 1);
}

foreach (var v in ls) {
    Console.WriteLine(v.ToString());
}
```

Output:

```
5
4
3
2
1
0
```

Comment: Since when can we use list like arrays!?! I remember being forced to use ElementAt. Is this as slow as ElementAt? That's one reason why I didn't use it and wrote this question

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can directly append to any iterable object while iterating.
But what you can do is create a temporary list like that:

```
var ls = new List<int>();
ls.Add(5);

var tempList = new List<int>();
foreach(var v in ls){
   if(v>0)
        tempList.Add(v-1);
}

//Update list
foreach(var v in tempList){
   ls.Add(v);
}

//Dont forget to clear the tempList if you need it again !
```

Answer (score 1):

To include the new additions in the iterations use the index:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ls.Count; i++)
{
    if (ls[i] > 0) ls.Add(ls[i] - 1);
}
```

---

To exclude them (and also keep the `foreach`) use a temporary copy of the List:

```
foreach (int i in ls.ToList())
{
    if (i > 0) ls.Add(i - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

IMO; This seems to need a recursive solution instead; something like this:

```
public List<int> AddByReduceNo(List<int> list, int no)
{
    if (no > 0)
    {
        list.Add(no - 1);
        return AddByReduceNo(list, no - 1);
    }

    return list;
}
```

That after `ls.Add(5)` use `ls = AddByReduceNo(ls, 5);`,
or just use `ls = AddByReduceNo(ls, 6);`

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the [BlockingCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287223(v=vs.110).aspx) class, and see if it fits your needs.

This class has a method [GetConsumingEnumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287186(v=vs.110).aspx) which gives you an `IEnumerable` that allows you to iterate over the items that were in the collection at that specific point in time.   In the meanwhile, another thread can continue adding items to the collection.

This is especially usefull if you have a consumer and a producer thread.